# why would iOS 9 safari stop firing change events for contenteditable elements?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, reactjs, contenteditable

context -- I work at company that does interactive quizzes for students, using contenteditable elements. we construct these using React (v0.13.3).

We started getting bug reports a few days ago that our program stopped working when students attached bluetooth keyboards to their iPads. upon further investigation, it seems like the combination of iOS 9 + mobile Safari + bluetooth keyboard causes contenteditable elements to no longer listen for keyup or change events (they are still triggering keydown events, however.)

Is this something anyone else is experiencing / has experienced before? How would you handle it?

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. It's quite odd that they would change this for any reason in iOS 9.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug through the "Apple Bug Reporter". Not sure how long it usually takes for these things to be addressed though.

Comment: update: we were able to fix it by binding to the OnInput event, instead of onKeyUp. still a very strange problem.

Comment: Me too experienced the same issue. When spacebar is pressed, it scrolls the window up instead of triggering an event but I was able to get it worked by binding the event listener to the text field instead of document or window.
$(document).bind("keypress", function(e){ ... }
to
$("#my_text_field").bind("keypress", function(e){ ... }

Comment: @raorao , while that works for character input, it does not work for keys such as arrow keys.Using oninput event got me 90% of the way though. Thanks!